# How To Create Settings/Preferences in an application

Tags: android

I am creating an application which I want the settings activity to change font size, change background color and put on and off splash screen sound.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Have you checked SharedPreference ? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: I haven't. Let me check and see if that works... Thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem. Just upvote and select the answer if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are N number of ways to go about this. The best one is sharedPreferences.

SharedPreferences allows you to store key-value pairs in a permanent preference file that persists across app sessions. SharedPreferences can only store primitive data which means you can use Strings / Integers / etc...

You have mentioned three things you want to save :

1. Font Size : Save as integer and do dimension conversion (if required).
2. Background color : Colors shoudl be declared in colors.xml as used in java using the ID (R.color.colorPrimary for example). The ID is an integer.
3. Splash screen sound enablement can be saved as boolean.